WPF button animation on command finished
I have a listView of items in my app, each item has some configuration and save button.
MainWindow:
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemVmList}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
              Padding="0">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ItemViewModel}">
                <local:ItemView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>

MainVM:
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IItemProvider _itemProvider;

    private readonly ISettingsManager _settingsManager;

    private ItemViewModel _selectedItem;

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> ItemVmList { get; set; }

    public ItemViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel(IItemProvider itemProvider, ISettingsManager settingsManager)
    {
        _itemProvider = itemProvider;
        _settingsManager = settingsManager;
        var itemList = _itemProvider.GetItems();
        ItemVmList = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>(
            itemList.Select(x => new ItemViewModel(settingsManager, x)));
        SelectedItem = ItemVmList.First();
    }
}

ItemView:
<Grid Height="50"
      Width="500">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="400" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"
               FontSize="18"
               Grid.Column="0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               Height="50" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
             FontSize="18"
             Width="50"
             Height="50"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Button Width="50"
            Height="50"
            Grid.Column="2">
        Save
    </Button>
</Grid>

ItemVM:
public class ItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly ISettingsManager _settingsManager;

    private readonly ItemModel _item;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _item.Name; }
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get { return _item.Value; }
        set
        {
            _item.Value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
        }
    }

    public ItemViewModel(ISettingsManager settingsManager, ItemModel item)
    {
        _settingsManager = settingsManager;
        _item = item;
    }
}

ISettingsManager have here only Save() method.
I want my save button to change style or play animation based on the result of the Save method (if true - green color and red if false). Also it would be good to move command logic from ItemVM if possible. I tried that with command, but I didn't find any way to somehow bind button style to Save() result.

You may add a property to ItemViewModel which indicates the result of the method. What exactly you find difficult to implement?

Well, I was looking for more elegant solution. Perhaps through event and event trigger on view side, so I can attach animation which will play when successful/unsuccessful response comes back.

I thought your view model has a reference to the SettingsManager instance and so the result of method of SettingsManager will be notified though view model and your view will wait until the view model indicates the result. Is it right?

Yes, it's right.

If so, one of straightforward ways is to use DataTrigger bound to a property of view model which indicates the result to change the Style's value or start the animation. There would no need to use a view element's event.
